# When trying to retrieve information from a View using a single parameter in myBatis, the result is null. When using static query, it works

Tags: java, spring, select, parameters, mybatis

I have a code that should retrieve some data from a view on Oracle Database (using mybatis).

It's a dynamic query which receives one parameter

silly code example:

```
//Repo Class
@Select("select surname, name from vw_example where name=#{name}")
@Results({
        @Result(property = "surname", column = "surname"),
        @Result(property = "name", column = "name"),

})
public List<Result> getSurname(@Param("name") String id)
```

```
//Test Class
@Autowired RepoClass repo;

@Test
public void testGetSurname(){
List<Result> result = repo.getSurname("Danilo");
AssertThat(result.size(),is(2));
}
```

Important thing (In the database I'm working on, the column for name is a CHAR[40] (Please don't ask why.. but I can't change it).

Considering that there are 2 records which contains "Danilo" as value for column "Name" in the Database, it should return 2 rows for me and Map to object "Result".

However, it's not happening. The Assert comes with actual: 0

Now, the crazy thing...

If I change this:

```
@Select("select surname, name from vw_example where name=#{name}")
```

to this:

```
@Select("select surname, name from vw_example where name='Danilo'")
```

It works like a charm!!

Info:
(I already tried passing the jdbcType (#{name,jdbcType=CHAR))

(It seems the parameter is being replaced, because I replaced the Select statement for a Insert with the parameter value and it goes fine)

Could someone help with this crazy thing?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the column is declared as `CHAR(40)`, the data in the DB is padded with spaces.

Option 1 : add spaces in Java code.

```java
List<Result> result = repo.getSurname(String.format("%-40s", "Danilo"));
```

Option 2 : cast the parameter in the query.

```sql
select surname, name from vw_example where name = cast(#{name} as char(40))
```

The literal version of the query works because [blank-padded comparison semantics](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements002.htm#BABJJGBI) is used, I guess.

> With blank-padded semantics, if the two values have different lengths, then Oracle first adds blanks to the end of the shorter one so their lengths are equal. (snip) If two values have no differing characters, then they are considered equal. This rule means that two values are equal if they differ only in the number of trailing blanks. Oracle uses blank-padded comparison semantics only when both values in the comparison are either expressions of datatype CHAR, NCHAR, text literals, or values returned by the USER function.